# I have an error with 7z when i exclude file type

Tags: powershell, 7zip

I made a script in powershell that at the time of compression I try to exclude the".lock" files

```bsh
7z.exe a -r- -mx1 -ssw -p"$zip_password" -x!*.lock test.zip $folderbackup
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. This tells me that the test.zip file is not found.

Thank you in advance for your help! :)

Comment: Try putting quotes around parameters that PowerShell might evaluate differently: `7z.exe a "-r-" "-mx1" "-ssw" "-p$zip_password" "-x!*.lock" test.zip $folderbackup`

Comment: You can also use the backtick (`\``) character to "escape" the dashes; e.g.: `\`-r-`